# Increment a line number using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to increment a line number in AngularJS??

```
$scope.line = 1;
$scope.next = function(){
  .....;
  .....;
  .....;
  $scope.line++;
};
```

I am using it as `Line:{{line}}`

But every element gets the same number. What should I do here contain them in an array and display them using repeat or is there any better way?

Comment: could you show some more code please

Answer (score 5):

`ng-repeat` provides access to array index of instance as `$index` in each child scope

Could try

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
   Line: {{$index+1}}    
</div>
```